# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aircraftRepository'

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, javabeans

I'm trying to configure spring and mongodb and I'm struggling with the following errors:

```
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Diskeeper Corporation\ExpressCache\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;D:\mysql\MySQL Utilities 1.4.3\;D:\mysql\MySQL Utilities 1.4.3\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Users\Abel\Downloads\spring3.1.3\apache-maven-3.2.3-bin\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;.
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:projectPiranha' did not find a matching property.
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2586 ms
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.12
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:39 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [678] milliseconds.
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:47 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:48 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 08 14:18:48 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:48 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:51 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'mongo' of type [class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@61f09174: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,aircraftRepository,aircraftResource,aircraftService,mongoTemplate,mongo,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@61f09174: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,aircraftRepository,aircraftResource,aircraftService,mongoTemplate,mongo,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aircraftRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate rest.repository.AircraftRepository.mongoTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4751)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5175)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate rest.repository.AircraftRepository.mongoTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:872)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:814)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:731)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver.<init>(DefaultDbRefResolver.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1961)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.objenesis.ObjenesisStd
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1320)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    ... 47 more

Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aircraftRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate rest.repository.AircraftRepository.mongoTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4751)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5175)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate rest.repository.AircraftRepository.mongoTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:872)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:814)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:731)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver.<init>(DefaultDbRefResolver.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1961)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.objenesis.ObjenesisStd
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1320)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    ... 47 more

Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/projectPiranha] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 08, 2014 2:18:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15670 ms
```

My libraries

> aopalliance-1.0.jar asm-3.1.jar commons-logging-1.2-javadoc.jar
>   commons-logging-1.2.jar jackson-core-asl-1.1.1.jar
>   javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
>   jaxb-api-2.1.jar jersey-client-1.18.jar jersey-core-1.18.jar
>   jersey-json-1.18.jar jersey-server-1.18.jar jersey-servlet-1.18.jar
>   jersey-spring-1.18.jar jettison-1.1.jar jsoup-1.7.3-javadoc.jar
>   jsoup-1.7.3.jar jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar mongo-2.7.2.jar
>   objenesis-1.3.jar org.springframework.aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.asm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.aspects-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.context.support-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.expression-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.instrument-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.orm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.oxm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.test-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.transaction-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
>   slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar spring-dao-2.0.8.jar
>   spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-data-commons-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-data-jpa-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-data-mongodb-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-data-solr-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar twitter4j-core-3.0.4-javadoc.jar
>   twitter4j-core-3.0.4-sources.jar twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar
>   twitter4j-stream-3.0.4-javadoc.jar twitter4j-stream-3.0.4-sources.jar 
>   twitter4j-stream-4.0.2.jar

My web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>projectPiranha</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyWebApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyWebApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


  </web-app>
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="rest">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration"/>
  </context:component-scan>


  <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="iffdb"/>
  </bean> 

  <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

NOTE: I'm not using Maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the libraries are wrong. Use maven because it will organize the dependencies itself.